# Инициализация переменной через is not. Как работает?

Tags: c#, .net

Сабж
Есть такой код

```
async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Only process Message updates: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message
    if (update.Message is not { } message)
        return;
    // Only process text messages
    if (message.Text is not { } messageText)
        return;

    var chatId = message.Chat.Id;

    Console.WriteLine($"Received a '{messageText}' message in chat {chatId}.");

    // Echo received message text
    Message sentMessage = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
        chatId: chatId,
        text: "You said:\n" + messageText,
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

Остальной код тут https://telegrambots.github.io/book/1/example-bot.html 
Вопрос в том как работает строчка `if (update.Message is not { } message)`
Я понимаю эту строчку так: Поле `update.Message` имеет тип `Message`. Мы проверяет соответствует ли присланное сообщение этому типу.
Далее мы проверяет само сообщения на `string` `if (message.Text is not { } messageText)` если это не текст то выходим из метода. 
Если я сделаю вот так `(message.Text is not string messageText)` все продолжит работать. Где можно почитать про этот сахар? И как это называется?
 Я имею в виду вот это `{ } messageText`

Comment: [Property Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#property-pattern)

Comment: [Pattern matching overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) - вообще, начинайте отсюда. И по ссылкам, по ссылкам! Внизу раздел See also.

Comment: [Оператор is](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) ([Шаблоны свойств](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#property-pattern)). Тут довольно просто, код `if (update.Message is not { } message) return;` будет аналогом `var message = test.Message; if (message == null) return;`, другими словами `is {}` это аналог `is not null`, что в свою очередь аналог `!= null`, в скобках можно задать сразу проверку конкретного свойства, будет вам и проверка на null и проверка значения свойства, ну и привести к типу.